# Count rows that have the same set of related records

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat

This is probably pretty simple but I can't figure this out.  Here are the tables I'm working with.

table_a

```
id  other_data
-------------
1      blah
2      foo
3      bar
```

table_b

```
ref_a  ref_c
-------------
1      1
1      2
2      3
3      3
```

table_c

```
id   name
----------
1    TestA
2    TestB
3    TestC
```

What I'm trying to get is something like this where I'm counting the number of rows (table_a) that have the same set of children (table_b).  I also want to be able to get related data from another table (The name from table_c).

```
TestA,TestB 1
TestC       2
```

I know it probably uses Group By and GROUP_CONCAT but I can't get this to work.

I tried this but it doesn't work.

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `table_c`.`name` separator ', ') as 'combo_text', COUNT(DISTINCT `table_a`.`id`)
  FROM `table_a`
    INNER JOIN `table_b`
      on `table_a`.`id` = `table_b`.`ref_a`
    INNER JOIN `table_c`
      on `table_c`.`id` = `table_b`.`ref_c`
    GROUP BY `table_b`.`ref_a`

Comment: Please format your question better (your example data and example output)

Comment: Can you please also edit your question to include what you tried that didn't work, per Stack Overflow's [good question guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.id, count(a.id) as count, GROUP_CONCAT(name) as names
FROM table_a a
JOIN table_b b ON (a.id = b.ref_a)
JOIN table_c c ON (b.ref_c = c.id)
GROUP BY a.id
```

<kbd>[sqlFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75ee5/5/0)</kbd>

based on your result you want something like this

```
SELECT names, count(count) as count FROM
  (SELECT a.id, count(a.id) as count, GROUP_CONCAT(name) as names
   FROM table_a a
   JOIN table_b b ON (a.id = b.ref_a)
   JOIN table_c c ON (b.ref_c = c.id)
   GROUP BY a.id
  )T1
GROUP BY names
```

<kbd>[sqlFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42e3d4/3/0)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks!  You got the right answer before I finished correcting my question lol.